# Problem with accented characters

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I'm having a problem on the accentuation of Python regular expression, I'm doing the following attempt:

```
import re
ER = re.compile(r'\w', re.L)
print(ER.sub('.','Maçã'))

..çã
```

Even using the `re.compile` passing the locale as an argument, the accents are not recognized.
Has anyone had this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe someone understanding Brazilian can translate this post to English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better off using `re.U` unicode flag.

If using Python 2.x you also need to specify the string as unicode, i.e.

```
print(ER.sub('.', u'Maçã'))
```

Comment: For me, this only works for python3 - on 2.7, I get '...�.�'

Comment: @Kimvais: In Python 2, you might also need to mark it as a unicode string: `u'Maçã'`

Comment: I had try use re.U in this way, but it didn't work.I got the same problem.

I tried get my default location: locale.getdefaultlocale()
, it returned >> ('pt_BR', 'UTF8')

Comment: @Kimvais: you need to prepend `u` to your string then, it seems.

Comment: @Michel: are you using `u'Maçã'` in your code?

Comment: i was using, but i got a problem, so a resolved using in this way unicode('Maça', ''utf-8). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html

> By default, Python's regex engine only considers the letters A through Z, the digits 0 through 9, and the underscore as "word characters". Specify the flag re.L or re.LOCALE to make \w match all characters that are considered letters given the current locale settings. Alternatively, you can specify re.U or re.UNICODE to treat all letters from all scripts as word characters. The setting also affects word boundaries.

Try using re.UNICODE.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem! I was trying use this code in the shell. So, i need to use in this way:

import re
ER = re.compile(r'\w', re.L)
ER.sub('.', unicode('Maça','utf-8'))

Thank you very much!!! :)